# How do I pass the props to DrawerItem Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a Navigation Drawer using React-Native and this is my `DrawerItem` component

```
<DrawerItem
  icon={({ color, size }) => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home-outline" size={30} color={colors.medium} />
  )}
  label="Home"
  onPress={() => {
    props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
  }}
/>
```

Since This component is being used several times in my drawer, I would like to create a Custom component like so

```
function AppDrawerItem({ label, ScreenName, icon, color = "medium" }) {
  return (
    <DrawerItem
      icon={({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} size={30} color={colors[color]} />
      )}
      label={label}
      onPress={() => {
        props.navigation.navigate[ScreenName];
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default AppDrawerItem;
```

When I try to implement this I am getting the following error

[image]

How do I pass the `ScreenName` as props?

---

This is how I am calling my custom-component

```
<DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
  <Drawer.Section style={styles.mainSection}>
    
    <AppDrawerItem
      label="Home"
      ScreenName="HomeScreen"
      icon="home-outline"
    />
  </Drawer.Section>
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the OP has accepted the answer, I sense a flaw here. What if you want to pass another function `onPress` event? The component you have designed is re-usable but restricts to screen-navigation. What if you want to, say Log-Out? You can make your component more re-usable this way.

Design your `AppDrawerItem` like so

```
function AppDrawerItem({ label, icon, onPress, color = colors.medium }) {
  return (
    <DrawerItem
      icon={({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} size={30} color={color} />
      )}
      label={label}
      onPress={onPress}
    />
  );
}

export default AppDrawerItem;
```

Now you can call it like so

```
<AppDrawerItem
  label="Home"
  icon="home-outline"
  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")}
/>
```

This is a better approach in my opinion.

Comment: You are right, this is a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your `ScreenName` prop.

You already destructured the props parameter as

`{ label, ScreenName, icon, color = "medium" }` which is why it can't find `props` variable.

What you can do is like this:

```
function AppDrawerItem({ label, ScreenName, icon, color = "medium", ...props}) {
//...
}
```

In this way you can access the `props` variable.

Also as you creating a Custom `DrawerItem` called `AppDrawerItem`, you  will also need to pass the navigation prop to it.

Do it like this:

```
<AppDrawerItem
      label="Home"
      ScreenName="HomeScreen"
      icon="home-outline"
      navigation={props.navigation}
    />
```

Comment: I am now getting "Uncaught Error: undefined is not an object(evaluationg 'props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Are you using react-navigation? Where are you calling your AppDrawerItem? Give the whole code

Comment: Yes I am using "react-Navigation" It works fine when I do not include the custom component, but throws this error when I use this. Updated my question to show the call.

Comment: I have updated my answer check that out.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, it is working now. Also the color prop is not working, any idea why that might be so?

Comment: What is your colors array? Do you want to use the color passed through AppDrawerItem component or the color you get from icon={({icon, size})=>{}} ?